Does Arya Samaj College Party/Cultured Party allow eating beef because it said diet is everyone’s own choice?
There’s 2 Sects in Arya Samajis called the College Party/Cultured Party which supports eating meat and the Mahatmas which are against eating meat
————————————————————————
The College Party said that diet was everyone’s choice and didn’t specifically say not to eat beef and said that eating meat (in general) is not against the Principles of Arya Samaj & they also said that Rishi Dayanand Ji is human and could still be incorrect
Also the College Party was saying this for the D A V College in Lahore which is in Pakistan where there’s lots of muslims and beef is already allowed in islam
Some College Party Leaders like Lala Lajpat Rai Ji still supported Gau Raksha but maybe it wasn’t for Religious Reasons I don’t know because he himself was okay with non-vegetarianism
————————————————————————
But the Mahatmas for sure said beef and other meat is banned and people who eat beef should be given the Death Penalty and people who eat other meat should be Punished in some other way by the King
————————————————————————
I read Books about Mahatma Hansraj Ji and Lala Lajpat Rai Ji and none of them specifically talked about the College Party banning beef
What do you think?
